# Use Euler's formula to find the least positive residue of $3^{100000} \mod 35$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is what I have so far, I just could not come to a solution and do not know where to go from here.

$\phi(35) = 35\cdot(1-(\frac {1}{5}))(1-\frac {1}{7}) = 24$

$3^{100000} = 3^{(24)(4166)} 3^{16} = 3^{16} = (3^4)^4= 81^4 = (4)^4 = 16 = 9$?

Is the answer to this $9$?
( The equal signs mean the congruence symbol, I just didnt know how to get it)

I do not know if I even did this right, or where to go from here!

Comment: How is $16 = 9$?

Comment: You made a mistake, $81$ is congruent to $11\bmod 35$, not $4$.

Comment: That one long single line makes no sense.  Obviously 35(1-1/5)(1-1/7) doesnt equal 243 to the 100,000 which obviously does not equal 3 to the 16 which obviously doesn't equal 16 which doesn't equal 9.  And the whole thing is a different answer than $\phi(35)$.  For eff sake!  Put in line breaks, and use $\equiv \mod 35$.  Otherwise this is utterly incoherent.

Comment: ah, much easier to read now.  $81^4 \equiv 11^4 \mod 35$ and $4^4 \ne 16$ but $16^2$.  Might be easier to do $3^{16} = 27^5*3 \equiv (-8)^5*3 = 8^4*-24 =64^2*11 \\equiv (-6)^2*11  = 36*11 \equiv 11 \mod 35$.

Comment: I apologize for being grouchy.  The single line made it hard to read and the run on sentence looked like $\phi(35) = 243^{1000000}$ which was hard to understand.  The equal signs are a minor offense but tolerable.  $\equiv$ is done as "\equiv".

Answer (score 1):

You were doing great:

$3^{100000}=3^{24\times 4166}3^{16}\equiv 3^{16}=(3^4)^4=81^4\equiv (11^2)^2=121^2\equiv 16^2=256\equiv11 \bmod 35$.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct till you reach $\,{\rm mod}\ 35\!:\ 4^{\large 4}\equiv 16.\,$ Correct is $\, 4\cdot 4^{\large 3}\equiv 4(64)\equiv 4(-6)\equiv 11$

Here is a simpler way that uses all *mental* arithmetic. $\, 3^{\large 4}\equiv 1\pmod 5,\ $ $3^{\large 6}\equiv 1\pmod 7,\,$ therefore we deduce further that  $\,\color{#c00}{3^{\large 12}\equiv 1}\,$ mod $5$ and $7,\,$ so also mod $35$

${\rm mod}\,\ \color{#c00}{12}\!:\,\ 10^{\large 5}\equiv (-2)^{\large 5}\equiv -32\equiv 4,\ $ so $\,\color{#0a0}{10^{\large 5}\! = 4 + 12k}$

${\rm mod}\,\ 35\!:\,\ 3^{\color{#0a0}{\large 10^{\Large 5}}}\equiv 3^{\large \color{#0a0}{4+12k}}\equiv 3^{\large 4}(\color{#c00}{3^{\large 12}})^{\large k}\equiv 3(27)\color{#c00}{\bf 1}^{\large k}\equiv 3(-8)\equiv 11$